# Is the Fourth Petition in the Lord's Prayer an adaptation of Proverbs 30: 7-9?

Tags: catholicism, lords-prayer, proverbs

WE read in Proverbs 30: 7-9 (NRSVCE):

> Two things I ask of you;
> do not deny them to me before I die:
> Remove far from me falsehood and lying;
> give me neither poverty nor riches;
> feed me with the food that I need,
> or I shall be full, and deny you,
> and say, “Who is the Lord?”
> or I shall be poor, and steal,
> and profane the name of my God.

It is possible that Jesus adopted, with suitable adaptation, the fourth petition  in The Lord's Prayer from Proverbs 30.   The deeper meaning of `Give us this day our daily [*epiousios*] bread 'has been the subject of long debates, including one on  the rarity  of the usage *epiousios* elsewhere.

By limiting the need for physical food `for the day' as if on  a` daily quota '  basis, Jesus wants us to steer clear of "..or I shall be full, and deny you.. " situation. Compare this with Yahweh's instruction to the  Israelite to eat only the manna they had gathered for each day (Exodus 16).

My question therefore is: According to Catholic scholars, is the Fourth Petition in the Lord's Prayer an adaptation of Proverbs 30: 7-9 ?

Comment: Could you clarify what is meant by "adopting"/"adapting" and what significance it has?

Comment: When you adopt something, you keep the original as it is, but when you adapt something, you modify it to suit to your requirement. For example, the phrase  ``ex  cathedra ' was adopted from Latin whereas the word `cathedral ' is an adapted one . Proverbs does  not speak of  `Daily Bread' but rather speaks of `just enough food' .  Jesus instructed his followers more than once , not to worry of what to eat and drink. But he did add a petition in the Lord's Prayer for daily food so that we remain conscious of our indebtedness to the Father for mundane provisions as well.

Comment: I'm still not sure of the significance of the question. We could speak of a normal human rabbi adapting something from Proverbs and teaching it to other Jews. But in the case of Jesus, He is the very same voice speaking in Proverbs 30 as in Matthew 6/Luke 11. So if anything, He is repeating Himself.